# 1/0 = 1/0 is it a true sentence?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have a doubt. I ask for help.

The Principle of Identity ("Anything is equal to itself") allows us to state, 
  without assigning any meaning to 1/0, that "1/0 = 1/0" is it a true sentence?

Or, in that case, would it be better to say that "1/0 = 1/0" is it an open sentence of type "x = x"?

Comment: Any well-defined expression is equal to itself. In programming, there's an object/class/whatever-you-wanna-call-it called "nil", which is not well-defined (for the most part), and so it fails to pass "nil = nil", to which some languages return false.

Comment: The answer is "it depends on your logic".  If every function in your logic is total, then yes it is probably a provable statement.  If you are working in a free logic where you can talk about things that might not exist, then yes it is probably provable.  If you are working in a logic based on partial functions without equality as a primitive, then it probably isn't a provable statement.  And if you are just doing casual mathematics outside of a formal framework, then you should never base anything on that statement.

Comment: Usually, in the semantics I am used to in free logic (e.g. in the SEP article https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#1.1 ), in order for a term $t$ to satisfy $t = t$, first $t$ has to be defined; otherwise $t = t$ is simply defined to be false when $t$ is undefined. So in these kinds of free logic, $1/0 = 1/0$ will not be provable when $1$, $0$, and $/$ are interpreted in the normal way as in the real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make sense (unless you are working with the extended real numbers, for example). You cannot apply the principle "anything is equal to itself" in this case, because $1/0$ is undefined, so there is no applicable "thing" or "self".

On the other hand, we can compare strings of text, so it is quite fine to assert the equality that
$$\text{"1/0" = "1/0"}$$
in the same way that "hello" = "hello".

Comment: I think we can rather say `"1/0" == "1/0"`, though in that sense, most programming languages will say 1/0 = $\infty$ and $\infty = \infty$

Comment: @Travis In some programming languages, yes, we would write `"1/0" == "1/0"`. But it is perfectly valid to talk about the equality of text outside a programming context.

Comment: I know, just the way you said it made me want to fix your programming syntax.

Answer (score 2):

$1/0$, interpreted as the evaluation of real number division with numerator $1$ and denominator $0$, is a *grammatical error*, since this pair of numbers is not in the domain of division.

Anything you say involving $1/0$ as a subexpression is therefore grammatically incorrect.

Trying to ascribing meaning to something despite grammatical errors is dangerous business. Usually, you can only get away with doing so when what you're *really* doing is making some implicit additions or corrections to remove the grammatical error (e.g. when facing $\frac{1}{x}$ in a setting where "$x$ is a real variable", to change the premise to "$x$ is a nonzero real variable").

There aren't many use cases where you can do that with $1/0$ as interpreted above — they mainly happen in settings where you would already know how to make sense of it, such as "I mean to do arithmetic in the real projective line".

Comment: More compactly, "1/0 = 1/0" is not a true sentence because it is not a sentence. (There are various ways of defining "/" so that it does become a sentence, in which case it will be true. Alternatively, the whole statement can be viewed as a shorthand for a totally different formula, e.g. $\exists y,z.\text{div}(1,0,y)\land\text{div}(1,0,z)\land y=z$ where $\text{div}(n,d,x)\equiv (n = dx)$ in which case it would be false.)

Comment: This answer appears to conflate syntax with semantics. What notion of grammatical correctness are you using? Is it grammatically incorrect for someone with no brother to form sentences involving the phrase "my brother"?

Comment: Of all the kinds of ways you could classify $1/0$ as an error, it is certainly not a grammatical one.  A grammatical error would be $1/+$ or $1/(3=3)$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Given a term $x$ of type $X$ and a term $f$ of type $X \to Y$, we write $f(x)$ for a term of type $Y$. When $X$ is a subtype of some product $U \times V$, for some operations we use infix notion when $x=(u,v)$. Division has type $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}) \to \mathbb{R}$. $(1,0)$ is not a term of type $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$. Thus, following the rules of grammar we cannot form the term $1/0$.

Comment: @DanielV: See above.

Comment: That is a type error, what you are describing.  A grammar is a very well established concept.  Grammatical errors are strictly less general than type errors because grammars are decidable.

Comment: @Hurkyl: so how about $1 / x$, where $x$ denotes the number of counterexamples to Goldbach's conjecture? Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: @RobArthan: Only if $x$ is of type "nonzero (extended) natural number". What you're overlooking in the point I imagine you're getting at is that one normally *implicitly* coerces $x$ into the nonzero naturals, an operation one can obtain from an assumption of Goldbach's falsity. If one were to write $1/x$ without having such an implicit coercion in mind, then it would be invalid.

Comment: @RobArthan: Of course, one can design syntax based on partial functions as well. And I think that might even better reflect what people are often trying to say. But nobody actually gets taught that.

Comment: Can you give references that support your use of the term "grammatically correct" in this context, please. And also to support your statement "nobody actually gets taught that".

Answer (score 1):

This principle of $x=x$ only applies to actual "things" ie. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ or any other defined ring where it applies by definition. Because $\frac{1}{0}$ isn't defined (or rather is *undefined by definition*), we can't apply a property to it. Similarly to the way that we can't say $\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)^0 = 1$ or that $\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)^{-1} = \frac{0}{1}$

Answer (score 0):

Standard first-order logic gives you no alternative: if you want a function symbol for division, then it must denote a total function and then $1/0 = 1/0$ has to be true. This offends a great number of people and so there is a lot of literature on logics that try to fit more nicely with human expectations about undefined terms. E.g., [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/). However there is no generally accepted solution and the standard first-order logic viewpoint wins for many people on the grounds of simplicity.

Comment: This is correct. At the same time the usual first-order logic treatment of fields does not have a division symbol at all, only multiplication, which is always defined. So it is not clear that $1/0 = 1/0$ should be interpreted as a statement in first-order logic.

Comment: I think you mean it is not clear that first-order logic is the best framework to deal with statements like $1/0 = 1/0$. I don't disagree with that, but if you do add division or reciprocal to the signature of a field in a first-order setting you have to live with $1/0 = 1/0$. Would you argue that you shouldn't interpret function application as a defined notion in first-order set theory?

Comment: You mean you would argue against interpreting function application as a defined notion in first-order set theory? I don't really see the point of what you are saying about what is "usual" or "normal' in first-order formalisations of field theory. I agree that division or reciprocal is not often included in first-order formalisations of field theory, but that doesn't preclude the possibility. I recollect that Hodges' book on model theory argues that if reciprocal **is** included in the signature of fields then we should require $1/0 = 0$., but whether or not we do that $1/0=1/0$ will hold.

Comment: By analogy if I read a sentence S: "the longest wing on a cat has the same length as the longest wing on that same cat", I wouldn't interpret this as a statement in FOL in which "the length of the longest wing" is a total function on the set of all animals.   Instead I would think that cats don't have wings and $S$ is nonsensical. Similarly, if I read $1/0 = 1/0$ without a very clear explanation of how I ought to read it, I would read it as nonsensical, not as a sentence of FOL.

Comment: Glancing at Hodges *Shorter Model Theory*, you might be looking at exercise 7 on page 10. There he says "Show that we can gives fields a signature which makes substructure = subfield and homomorphism = field embedding, provided we are willing to let $0^{-1} = 0$. *Most mathematicians seem to be unwilling, and so the normal custom is to give fields the same signature as rings.* (His emphasis) I think this supports your point that viewing division as a total function "offends a great number of people".

Comment: Thanks for the quote from Hodges. That is what I had in mind. Your analogy about winged cats doesn't give me any idea about how you would interpret $f(x) = f(x)$ as a statement in first-order set theory? I am genuinely interested in how you extend your (understandable) point of view to this slightly more general case.